# Testing In-App purchasing Iphone

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I am writing an app for newsstand with free subscription but the product identifier i am using always comes back in the invalid set when making the request.

I have used this tutorial:
http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/

I have:

1) created an Appid (fsfe4.com.myapp.myappdesc)

1a) signed the paid ios app contract and filled in the banking/tax info

2) put that appid as the bundle id (com.myapp.myappdesc) in the plist

3) downloaded developer and distrubtion provisioning profiles (developer profile does not have wildcard)

4) updated the code signing identity (both the Debug and 'Any IOS SDK' has the iPhone developer referencing the developer profile i created and downloaded)

5)  added the code

6) created and added info for the app on itunes connect (turned newsstand on, uploaded photos and filled out all the info)

7)  compiled and archived the xcode project, uploaded it to itunes connect, rejected the binary.

8) created the in app purchase (free subscription), and attached it in the 'view details' part of the application.

- I get this notice:
  The first In-App Purchase for an app must be submitted for review at the same time that you submit an app version. You must do this on the Version Details page. Once your binary has been uploaded and your first In-App Purchase has been submitted for review, additional In-App Purchases can be submitted using the table below. Note that free In-App Purchase subscriptions may only be submitted with a version that is enabled for Newsstand.
  I am not entirely sure what that means.

9) waited 24 hours

10) tried again with no luck

I have re-archived,uploaded and rejected my app a couple of times. I haven't changed the version # in itunes connect but i don't think that should matter.

According to Apple's guide it specifically says that I should not have uploaded the binary and rejected it:

- *Important* DO NOT upload the development binary to iTunes Connect until the application is ready for App Review approval. If the binary is present in iTunes Connect and it is not
  fully functional, App Review will review the binary and likely reject the development binary. Testing In App Purchase will fail if you or App Review reject your most recent 
  binary in iTunes Connect. The workaround in this case is to upload a binary without In App Purchase features that can get approved by App Review. 
  Once the binary is approved, resume testing the binary with In App Purchase features.

That goes against every other tutorial i have seen. Is there a way to remove the binary to get it back to the pre uploaded binary state so that I can test? should i just delete the app and start over? if I do delete it can I use the same bundle id and same app name?

Comment: The same author who wrote the post above has a list of common problems when you have invalid product IDs http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that I didn't delete the app from the device and reinstall it after i had gone through [the checklist here](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids).

So much time wasted. Sigh.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running your app with development provision or distribution provision? 
Are you running your app with same app id / provision for which you have uploaded the in app purchase?

Follow this article - http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases

Comment: the scheme build configuration for 'run' is debug and the code signing for debug and debug->any ios is the developer provision (no * - it includes the full appid). I only have one appid so they all are using it (i just selected it from the dropdown when creating my provisioning profile). I am also running it on an iPad so that rules out the mistake of running it in the ios simulator and getting nothing.