# How can I test inapp purchases when the connection fails right after making a purchase?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, storekit

It seems like I finally got my inapp purchases working. Now I would like to test for restoring unprocessed purchases (like when the internet connection fail right after you pay for the inapp, so you were charged money, but you haven't received the product yet because Apple couldn't contact the device).

I suppose that I could pay for an inapp, and then, suddenly, smash my router and cut off the wifi. But perhaps there is a more professional way to test for inapp purchase failure restoration?

Comment: How about reinstalling the app and clicking 'restore purchases'?

Answer (score 0):

Well you don't need to go into all that physical pain of smashing your router and stuff :)... Please check these links . There are more elegant and simple ways of testing an in-app purchase.

[How To Test An InApp purchase](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/26163-how-to-test-in-app-purchase.html)

[Testing In-App purchasing Iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838117/testing-in-app-purchasing-iphone)

[I cannot get in app purchase test to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780440/i-cannot-get-in-app-purchase-test-to-work)

Also if you would go through this tutorial at the end they do explain how to test an inapp purchase plus an apple store link to guide you through

[In App Purchase Tutorial](http://www.nixsolutions.com/blog/development/iphone/in-app-purchase-tutorial/)

[Apple InApp Store](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/DevelopingwithStoreKit/DevelopingwithStoreKit.html)

Hope these help :).

Answer (score 0):

As you know, when you purchase any product the transaction process takes place, if the product is paid/consumable.

Now, for example you are going to purchase any product. You begin the transaction process for that. After making successful transaction your network connection goes off. Now what will you do??

-> The answer depends upon two following scenarios.

**1.** The Product is non-consumable

**2.** The Product is consumable

**Case 1:** You will have the restore purchases option to restore your transaction

**Case 2:** You will get a receipt with the product. & you need to send back the receipt with the confirmation & your digital signature.

Read out "**`Receipt Validation`**" concept for it, as described below.

When you make an In-App Purchase, you can’t 100% trust that the response that comes over the network saying “everything went OK” really came from Apple without using a technique called “receipt validation.”

When you make an In-App Purchase, Apple sends you back a special piece of data called a “receipt.” This is a private piece of data that records cryptographically-signed information about the transaction. The idea is that for your app to be secure, you shouldn’t blindly trust that a purchase completed – you should send the receipt to a special “receipt validation” server that Apple has set up to double-check that everything is OK.